# Android app crashes when nothing is entered and button is pressed

Tags: java, android, if-statement, crash

Hi I am working on an Android App and would like to ask for some help:
The user enters a numbers on a editText and presses/clicks the button to get a conversion displayed in answer field text.

Unfortunately if nothing is entered and the user clicks the button the application crashes.

Could anyone help me put it into code:

If editText is empty and button is clicked display 0.00 in the answer text field.

or the other way if editText is empty and button is pressed display toast message

?

If anyone understands what I am talking about and can help I would greatly appreciate it as I want to improve my applications for users before publishing ;-)

my updated code:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
Double num1 = 0.0;
final String myStr = editText.getText().toString();
if (!myStrisEmpty())
{
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(myStr);
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.noinput),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Problem is this:
 final String myStr = editText.getText().toString();   //editText is in red
    if (!myStrisEmpty())  //(!myStrisEmpty()) is in red

Ive been trying for hours and days to acomplish this task. simply have made a app where the user enters a number then clicks the button to convert the number and display it below into a textview answer. If i dont enter anything and click the button the app crashes. I would like a toast message instead of it crashing saying "Please Enter a Number"

Comment: is that a null pointer exception

Comment: You aint checking for when the edit text is empty...i am sure that is your problem.. you should have a condition that checks if the edit text is empty or not..if it is, then you handle it by displaying a toast to the user

Comment: im trying it still crashes any ideas sorry for my lack of skill.....if(editText.length()==0){
            Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Please Enter Weight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: You should post the contents of your LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert an empty string to a number.
What you should do is a check if the string is not empty:

Change these lines:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Double num1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
```

to

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
Double num1 = 0.0;
final String myStr = editText.getText().toString();
if (!myStr.isEmpty())
{
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(myStr);
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.noinput),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You might replace getResources().getString(R.string.noinput) (set it in your `/values/strings.xml` folder) by a hardcoded string (but that's not a good practice), like "You didn't enter any value"

And this:

```
answer.setText(ans.toString());
```

should be:

```
answer.setText("" + ans);
```

Comment: im just trying to make a message that if field is empty and button is pressed for it not to crash and say "please enter weight"  if(editText.length()==0){
            Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Please Enter Weight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: `if(editText.length()==0)` is **wrong**. read my code: you have to get the text out of your editText (i called it `edt` and the text is `myStr`).

Comment: I have no idea sorry, updated my question if it helps and thank you for your time and kindness in helping me improve my app

Comment: I tried it and still the !isEmpty is redwritting giving me error. Is there a easier way for me just to code something like:

Comment: a toast or validation message that if user doesn't enter any numbers and presses button a message will be displayed saying "Error please enter a number" or something like that/ sorry for your time and my lack of understanding, maybe i need more sleep or more coffee lol thanks for your help eitherway

Comment: Updated my answer with a Toast.

Comment: updated my code: unfortunatly still not working editText is red where it says final String myStr = editText.getText().toString(); and if (!isEmpty(myStr)) isEmpty still in red... so close its driving me crazy been figuring this out for ages thanks for any further help in achieving this little hurdle

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I fixed the isEmpty syntax.

Comment: I also removed the EditText assignment by mistake. Anf the R.string had to be getResources().getString(R.string... Reedited my answer. Now it should work

Comment: still the red for editText. and !strisEmpty ohh well im off to bed thanks for helping me out your time effort and kindness I hope somehow i can achieve this just simply so it doesnt crash on users funny ive completed the app just tidying up testing phase....seem i spend more time on testing and coding for preventable crashes....night and thanks once again TOP NOTCH Bob Malooga

Comment: here `if (!myStrisEmpty())` you miss a DOT: `if (!myStr.isEmpty())`. Also make sure you have an EditText whiuch has an `android:id="@+id/editText"` in your layout (mind the **+** sign).

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND MISSION ACCOMPLISHED still a little bug but il get onto it fist thing in the morn well deserve sleep thanks talk tomoz

Comment: Thank you, "Legend" is too much. "Myth" is enough... ;) Good night.

Comment: Myth it is ;-) have a great day will give you credits when i get some more rep all working beautiful now thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you weel, what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();
    if (input.isEmpty())
        textView.setText("0.00");
    else{
    // do whatever conversions
        textView.setText(result);
   }
```

Comment: public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        //do something when the button is clicked
        EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Double num1=Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
        Double ans= num1 * 2.20462;

        TextView answer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answertxt);
        answer.setText(ans.toString());

        if (editText.isEmpty())
        answer.setText("0.00");
    }

Comment: i can not comment on the topic because of my reputation, so i'll leave it here. Try to use myStr.IsEmpty() method or StringUtils.isEmpty(myStr)

Comment: you are more or less on the right path and thank you for your kindness and help unfortunatlely still not working grrr i think i might go to bed been on this for few days and many hours...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are calling the toString() method on a primitive. Try this:

Replace:

```
answer.setText(ans.toString());
```

With:

```
answer.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
```