# Android app crashes when nothing is entered when button is pressed

Tags: java, android, crash

Trust you are well. You helped a fellow member out for a query ([Android app crashes when nothing is entered and button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029262/android-app-crashes-when-nothing-is-entered-and-button-is-pressed)) on App crashing when nothing is entered in the EditText field. I am having the same issue but my application still crashes when I input your code correctly.

I would appreciate if you could look at my code below and inform me what I may have to change to make it work. I am a confused with what the num1 was being used for, and as you can see I can't change num1 into test as it is being used for my onClick to generate an email.

Thank you in advance.

```
public void calculateTS(View v){
    String status;
    test = Double.parseDouble(edtResult.getText().toString());
    String result = String.format("%.2f", test);
    Log.d("MyActivity", result);

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id. edtResult);
    Double num1 = 0.0;
    final String myStr = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!myStr.isEmpty())
    {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(myStr);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.noinput),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if( test < 20.5) {
            status = "Poor";
        } else if (test >= 20.5 && test < 50.5){
            status = "Average";
        } else if (test >= 50.5 && test < 100.0) {
            status ="Well Done"; }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Result Feedback...");
        alertDialog.setMessage(status);
        alertDialog.setButton("Acknowledged", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(test< 20.5)){
                    String email = "test@test.com";
                    String subject = "Feedback";
                    String message = "Hello,\n\nTest.";
                    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND );
                    emailIntent.setType( "plain/text" );
                    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email } );
                    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject );
                    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message );

                    startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( emailIntent, "Send Mail..."), 1234);
                }
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: @Der Golem Please Help with the above

Comment: You are in the happy position of having a debugger. On what line does it crash, what exception do you get?

Comment: Please give us more details like erros, exceptions got...you also can use Log.d("DEBUG", "to do debug") to do some debug and check where you are getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your cases mixed up.  If the field is empty, simply Toast that the field is empty and do nothing.  If the field is not empty, then do all the other stuff.

```
//This should be a member variable
Double test;    

public void calculateTS(View v){
    String status;


    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtResult);
    Double num1 = 0.0;
    final String myStr = editText.getText().toString();
    if (myStr.isEmpty())
    {
        //num1 = Double.parseDouble(myStr); //looks like this is not used?

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.noinput),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        test = Double.parseDouble(myStr);
        String result = String.format("%.2f", test);
        Log.d("MyActivity", result);

        if( test < 20.5) {
            status = "Poor";
        } else if (test >= 20.5 && test < 50.5){
            status = "Average";
        } else if (test >= 50.5 && test < 100.0) {
            status ="Well Done"; }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Result Feedback...");
        alertDialog.setMessage(status);
        alertDialog.setButton("Acknowledged", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(test< 20.5)){
                    String email = "test@test.com";
                    String subject = "Feedback";
                    String message = "Hello,\n\nTest.";
                    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND );
                    emailIntent.setType( "plain/text" );
                    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email } );
                    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject );
                    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message );

                    startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( emailIntent, "Send Mail..."), 1234);
                }
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Awesome thank you ever so much Daniel truly appreciate your help working brilliantly.

Comment: Hi just a quick question just been testing the application and noticed that none of the status appear on screen if the value inputted into the editText is either >= 20.5 & < 50.5 displaying "Average" or for >= 50.5 & < 100.0 as "Well Done".

Comment: Ahh, I just noticed that inside your `onClick()` you have `if(test< 20.5)){`, so it will only perform your logic there for the "Poor" case.  Did you intend to create different logic there for each case?

Comment: Yes, so the different onscreen prompt should appear depending upon what the user inputs in the editText field

Comment: Hi there, I just tried the code, and it is working just fine for me.  I get the alertDialog for all inputs.  If you are still having problems, open up a new question and provide as much info as you can about this issue.